# Update form field with AJAX Symfony2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have form:

```
<form action="{{ path('book_create') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.bookFoto) }}
    {{ form_row(form.bookTitle) }}
    {{ form_row(form.categories) }}
    <p class="new_category">+ Add category</p>
    {{ form_row(form.authors) }}
    <p>+ Add author</p>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

When I click 'Add category' I load with AJAX form for create new Category Entity, and save it with AJAX too.
But I don't understand how can I update entity field type `categories` without reloading form.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Saving your Book entity with all categories with AJAX? Or what?

Comment: I want add new category if i need and not reload this form fully

Comment: But why do you do AJAX savings for categories? If you create categories with ajax you then need to paste your new category ids to the form. But the standard way is more easy.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with embedded collection you need to manage your form with JS. Symfony has built-in helper for it. It is called `prototype` and used for populating form with new rows of embedded collection:

```
<ul class="tags" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.categories.vars.prototype)|e }}">
    ...
</ul>
```

You can read more at official documentation:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html